# Acrylic Material with Light Transmission

Tags: materials, lighting

I've tried so many things that I know of and I can't figure this material out. For reference, I have an example of what I want to create. To be clear I'm going for the floor material.

[image]

To me, it looks like the floor is illuminated from the bottom, I'm thinking this because the lights hitting floor in the middle are turning the floor white. So I'm assuming the floor is a white acrylic material with just a little light transmission, as you can see it's also very glossy. So I have a white floor material and then I have an emission material at the bottom. In the pictures you'll see a big round shape on the floor, that's the large panel light beneath the floor and the the fresnel keeps doing this. ANyway here are my results.

[image]

Then I figured out that GGX will let me transmit light but it doesn't work, this is **transmission** and **transmission roughness** cranked. One problem that persists is the fresnel is being really weird or I just don't have the right settings to get what I need.

[image]

Comment: what kind of lights do you have in your scene?  There are a LOT of spotlights in that studio scene.  It'll be hard to duplicate the scene accurately without a similar lighting setup.

Comment: The difficult part is the spot lights don't really show up much with the big panels on the walls and floors. The emission panels throw out a lot of light. Right now I'm just trying to get the floor material right.

Comment: is that round shape from a big spotlight?

Comment: No it's from the light beneath the floor

Comment: oh, I don't think that's what's going on there...I think it's like this: https://imgur.com/a/73Rf5os ... see the long harsh shadow of the guy on the left side in your image?

Comment: Never mind I might have fixed my problem. After extruding the floor and making it 1" in thickness, it did what I wanted to do. It was just a plane before so I'm guessing the light needs something to bounce around in in order to achieve the effect I want.

Comment: ah, ok, I was just about to attach a blend that seems to work fine for me...but I do have thickness to the floor.  http://www.mediafire.com/file/j1ozq744c5dq6zc/panel-floor.blend1/file  if interested

Comment: I don't think the material will be a problem now, but thank you for your help. When I start to ask more questions I tend to get to the answer sooner. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All it took was extruding thickness to my floor sorry I'm an idiot LOL

Comment: that's the best way to learn imho!